# Dividir array bidimensional em 2 arrays simples - PHP

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Estou realizando adaptações num sistema antigo e preciso criar uma nova rotina para dividir um array bidimensional em 2 arrays simples.

Digamos que a variável `$query` receba o array abaixo:

```
$query = array("SELECT * FROM teste WHERE nome in (?) and id in (?)", array('aaa', 1));
```

Meu objetivo é dividir esse array e fazer com que uma variável `$sql` receba:

`SELECT * FROM teste WHERE nome in (?) and id in (?)`

E outra, chamada `$arg`, receba:

`array('aaa', 1)`

Já tentei fazer essa divisão com `implode`, mas o retorno não foi o esperado.
E com `explode` sempre obtenho `NULL`.

Existe alguma função nativa do PHP que faça essa divisão? Ou pelo menos alguma rotina que possa fazer isso por meio da força bruta?

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso usando o construtor `void list ( mixed $varname [, mixed $... ] )`

PHP:

```
$query = array("SELECT * FROM teste WHERE nome in (?) and id in (?)", array('aaa', 1));


list($sql, $arg) = $query;

echo $sql;
echo PHP_EOL.'-----------------------'.PHP_EOL;
var_dump($arg);
```

Resultado:

```
SELECT * FROM teste WHERE nome in (?) and id in (?)
-----------------------
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "aaa"
  [1]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava, obrigado!